# Examples of recursive predicates

Tags: recursion, design-patterns, functional-programming, scheme

In Stone's *Algorithms for Functional Programming*, he gives a design pattern for recursively defined predicates, which in Scheme is

```
(define (check stop? continue? step)
  (rec (checker . arguments) 
    (or (apply stop? arguments) 
        (and (apply continue? arguments) 
             (apply (pipe step checker) arguments)))))
```

where `pipe` is the author's function to compose two functions in diagrammatic order, `((pipe f g) x = (g (f x))`.

So, for instance, to test whether a function is a power of two, you could define

```
(define power-of-two? (check (sect = <> 1) even? halve))
```

where `(sect = <> 1)` is the author's notation for currying, equivalent to `lambda x: x == 1`.

Clearly a lot of predicates *could* be implemented recursively but it would not be useful. And clearly there are some recursive predicates that wouldn't use this pattern, like predicates on trees.

What are some classic predicates that fit this pattern? I guess testing if something is in the Cantor set, but that's almost the same as the above.

Comment: This question seems like a better fit for [cs.se].

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are asking but your example is a classical example of programming with combinators.

The combinators are functions that take as input functions and return functions.

Combinators are fundamental in functional programming.  Using them you can implement everything. For instance, if you define a data structure for an object as a function you can compose objects using some combinator and get a new object.

The combinator from your exemple seems to be useful to check some predicate about the composition of some monads.